How can export pdf
When exporting PDF files with multiple tables using the Rotativa library, an issue arises where table headers overlap with the table data if the data extends beyond a single page, resulting in unclear and unreadable content.
public ActionResult ReportGeneratePdfTest(string projectname, int? year, int? month)
        {
            try
            {
                ViewBag.year = year;
                ViewBag.Month = month;
                ReportsNewViewModel obj = new ReportsNewViewModel
                {
                    Year = year,
                    Month = month,
                    ProjectName = projectname
                };
                ViewBag.layoutcase = true;

                if (year.HasValue && month.HasValue)
                {
                    obj = ReportsSectionCallMethod(projectname, (int)year, (int)month);
                }

                // Generate the PDF with custom settings
                return new ViewAsPdf("ReportsSectionMethod", obj)
                {
                    FileName = "Under_Construction_Thermal_Project_Broad_Status_Report.pdf",
                    PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(10, 10, 10, 10),
                    PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A3,
                    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
                    CustomSwitches = "--page-offset 0", 
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception or handle it as needed
                throw;
            }
        }


I'd consider that a bug and it should be reported as such to the project. Best would be to extract a [mre] and file a bug with them including that repro.
